# How do I display information about a node's author on the full node and not the teaser view?

Tags: 7, theming

I have added the following to my node.tpl

```
<?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
 <?php print $user_picture; ?><?php print $name; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This displays the authors info on the node itself, but also the teaser. How do I change the code to remove it from the teaser, but still keep it on the node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pop an `if ($page):` condition around it:

```
<?php if ($page): ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <?php print $user_picture; ?><?php print $name; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif;?>
```

In the context of node.tpl.php `$page` is defined on the [docs page](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7) as a:

> Flag for the full page state.

Comment: Perfect. Thamks Clive. Any thoughts on this one too? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/33913/how-can-i-add-a-header-and-footer-field-to-all-drupal-generated-blocks